# Company logo blocks user icon

Tags: html, css

In my header, there is a hamburger menu, the company logo and a user icon.

If i only put my hamburger menu and my user icon in, everything is in a row and its even.
But if i put the company logo in, the user icon moves a little bit down and isn't in the row anymore.

Does someone know what i did wrong and how i can fix this?
I tried to move it with padding-top, margin and so on. But it didnt changed anything. It is like freezed.

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
 if(e.target.type == "checkbox")
     return;
 else{
    var elem = $('#menuToggle').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    if($(elem).prop('checked')){
      $(elem).trigger('click');
    }
 }   
});
```

```css
.headlogo {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto;
 
}
.userlogo {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 
}
/*
 * Made by Erik Terwan
 * 24th of November 2015
 * All rights reserved
 *
 *
 * If you are thinking of using this in
 * production code, beware of the browser
 * prefixes.
 */

body
{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.1s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: black;
}
nav {
 display: inline-block;
}
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: white
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  float: left;
  background: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's fade it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav role="navigation">
   <div id="menuToggle">
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  <img class="headlogo" src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/4483c1-1504701412.png">
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-user userlogo" aria-hidden="true"></i>

 </header>
```

You can remove the logo by deleting the src in the img with the class "headlogo".

Thanks to everyone who can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `top` and `left` styles to `0` from the `#menuToggle` and then try using flexbox on the `header` tag.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxqzw8sz/2/

Comment: After optimizing it for mobile phones, it works finally. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your logo is `display: block` - by default, `display: block` elements take up the full width of their container, so that forces the next element (user icon) to go onto the next line. You should really use flexbox to get the effect you want (see [Ovidiu Unguru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076548/422845) and [included JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxqzw8sz/2/) for details on the flexbox implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Block level elements occupy the full width of the browser unless they are given a width or floated or positioned in some other fashion. That is why your icon drops down one level. There just is no room for it.

As an example, remove the `display:block;` from your image and you'll see the icon move up.

I'd offer more advice but doing that affects your menu placement so you'll need to work on that.